# Deterministic build not creating binary equivalent DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have some DLL files in my git repo built from a .Net Framework Class Library. These shouldn't need to be updated every time I rebuild the solution, unless there are code changes in them.

So I added `<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` to my .csproj files in the hope that they will be binary equivalent each time I rebuild without any code changes.
This does not seem to work, however, as the DLLs are marked as "changed" every time I build.

So how can I get Visual Studio 2017 to build deterministic DLL files that are binary equivalent each time I rebuild them so that they don't show up as "changed" every time I rebuild?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about how to make it so when you hit "Build" in Visual Studio, it doesn't rebuild the project unless there are code changes. As far as I'm aware the "deterministic" flag doesn't change Visual Studio's decision-making, so maybe there's something in your build process that is causing Visual Studio to rebuild even when you haven't made code changes.

Comment: Not quite. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/deterministic-compiler-option) states that the `<Deterministic>` flag _"Causes the compiler to produce an assembly whose byte-for-byte output is identical across compilations for identical inputs."_ So even if the same code is compiled on two different computers, the DLLs should still be identical... which they are not in my case